# What to roll to unjam gun in Shadowrun 5e

Tags: skills, weapons, shadowrun-sr5

Let's say player rolled a glitch and weapon is jammed. What skill should he roll to unjam it?

I tried to find this info in core rulebook but I failed. It makes no sense to me to use Armorer (Logic) skill here. Maybe it's just a matter of spending complex action?

Comment: I'm not really familiar w/5E SR, but I'd probably rule that whatever skill you use for the gun is also the skill to unjam it.  Training in the use of firing guns also involves in basic maintenance and dealing with regular issues - like jams.  That said, you might skip the roll altogether and as you mention - just involve eating an action to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading somewhere (might be in an earlier edition though) that all you needed to do was roll the appropriate weapon skill with an hard-ish treshold.

I'd say you'd have to seriously repair a weapon if you get a critical glitch though. A shell exploding the middle of your barrel wont be fixed by hitting it once or twice against a wall.

I'll try to find out where i read that.

Answer (score 3):

The core rules don't explicitly cover this. If the GM states that the gun is jammed because of a critical glitch, then they should also come up with what needs to be done to unjam it.

If it were a critical glitch, I would say they have the take an Automatics test with a Hard threshold. If it were a simple glitch, I would way they have to use a complex action to unjam it.

Hope this helps!